# Ajax request is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

When i  try to POST my `JSON`  am not able to see any request and also my local server not even getting these calls.

This is my ajax part

```
function callserver(){
  var markers = {"regDate" : 1451330123000, "specialities" : " ", "isActive" : true, "mobileNo" : "876876","id" : 0, "completed" : false,"mcname" : "", "password" : "hgh","role" : "SuperAdmin,Consultant","logins" : [],"email" : "testtestets@test.com","name" : "regcg","organization" : "hghjg"};    
  alert(markers);    
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data:markers,
    headers: {
      'Accept':'application/vnd.company.productname-v1+json',
      'X-PD-Authentication':'42</B7Tg8o5C7`7<7Ar0?]pJs`@Noplt>I1m>QYQn[v=osDl:unWyx`SYqBK@0?w',
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://x.x.x.x:9001/users",
    success: function(data) {
      alert("success");
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("failure");
    }
  });

}
```

Till `alert(markers);` is working but after that

am not getting "Success" or "failure" alert.
Console screenshots

[image]

[image]

Please help me

Comment: Any issue in console???

Comment: any errors on console?

Comment: Check your console for errors!

Comment: @Bangalore Did you add jQuery?

Comment: `$.ajax is not a function`, meaning jQuery is not loaded.

Comment: @Bangalore In your console try `$.fn.jquery` and say what's happening?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:2:5
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:904:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:837:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:693:21)

Comment: Sorry, try `$.fn.jquery`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99190/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-bangalore).

Comment: @PraveenKumar Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jquery' of undefined
    at <anonymous>:2:5
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:904:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:837:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:693:21)

Comment: @Bangalore Looks like you are not including jQuery library at all.

Comment: What does `typeof jQuery` say?

Comment: Sorry, show us the full code?

Comment: any other chance to check

Comment: @Bangalore Try the above comment.

Comment: @PraveenKumar  typeof jQuery
"function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are [not ready to show the full HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509456/ajax-request-is-not-working/34509714#comment56760373_34509456), it looks like you are using another library with jQuery, because [jQuery works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34509456/ajax-request-is-not-working/34509714#comment56760472_34509456). So kindly change all the `$` to `jQuery`:

```
function callserver(){
  var markers = {"regDate" : 1451330123000, "specialities" : " ", "isActive" : true, "mobileNo" : "876876","id" : 0, "completed" : false,"mcname" : "", "password" : "hgh","role" : "SuperAdmin,Consultant","logins" : [],"email" : "testtestets@test.com","name" : "regcg","organization" : "hghjg"};    
  alert(markers);
  // Change here
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data:markers,
    headers: {
      'Accept':'application/vnd.company.productname-v1+json',
      'X-PD-Authentication':'42</B7Tg8o5C7`7<7Ar0?]pJs`@Noplt>I1m>QYQn[v=osDl:unWyx`SYqBK@0?w',
      'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
    dataType: "json",
    url: "http://x.x.x.x:9001/users",
    success: function(data) {
      alert("success");
    },
    error: function () {
      alert("failure");
    }
  });
}
```